# Help! I can't install anything because of subprocess error [SOLVED]

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, software-center, dpkg

I don't know what happened but suddenly with no reason no apps and packages could get installed. When i want to install a package with `sudo apt-get install <package>` I get this error:

```
mpiuser@host:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  docbook-xml libcairo-perl libept1.4.12 libglib-perl libgtk2-perl
  libpango-perl librarian0 rarian-compat sgml-data
Suggested packages:
  docbook docbook-dsssl docbook-xsl docbook-defguide libfont-freetype-perl
  libgtk2-perl-doc perlsgml w3-recs opensp libxml2-utils dwww menu deborphan tasksel
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docbook-xml libcairo-perl libept1.4.12 libglib-perl libgtk2-perl
  libpango-perl librarian0 rarian-compat sgml-data synaptic
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,441 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin: Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is also correct when i want to install an app from Ubuntu software center.
The error message is like this:

[image: software center error]

What Should I do? I don't want to re-install my ubuntu.

Comment: No, the main part of the error is `/etc/environment: line 2: /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin: Is a directory`. Then Apt just informs you that an error occurred.

Comment: go to software and updates and check two tabs called **ubuntu software**  and **other software** and check options in **ubuntu software** .You can type from terminal `sudo software-properties-gtk
` to go to **software and updates**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code solved my problem

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst.bad
```